# How to configure geodjango on windows10?

Tags: django, windows-10, gdal, geodjango

I am working on a geodjango project on windows-10. I have been following the tutorial and the installation guide from the [geodjango documentation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481). I have installed all required packages and executed the bat script.

Python version: Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:13:57) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

OSGEO version: GDAL 2.4.1, released 2019/03/15

Initially I had to reconfigure my virtual environment to have a 64-bit python version matching that of the OSGEOW4 application.

I've tried the solutions answered for questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139044/geodjango-on-windows-could-not-find-the-gdal-library-oserror-winerror-12/49159195#49159195) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140241/geodjango-on-windows-try-setting-gdal-library-path-in-your-settings).

Those solutions include:

- Setting the environment variables before at the beginning of the *settings.py* of the django project
- Defining the GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH
- Adding the gdal version to the django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py

I have not yet tried the alternative of installing the gdal from a binary file. I do not understand why I would not be able to configure with the OSGEO application.

The error present in the command prompt when executing `python manage.py check` is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()

[...]

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Seems like it is an issue that many encounter.

A concise yet complete answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up downloading the binary GDAL file from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). The version that worked for my Python version was GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.

Some key points if you are stumbling upon the same issue:

- Make sure the python version in your virtual environment is the same bit size as the gdal version
- to enable execution of .bat scripts you must change the Set-ExecutionPolicy variable

#### The steps of my configuration are the following:

1. Download postgres with postgis spatial extension from edm
2. Create Django project with a specific environment
3. Open powershell and navigate to Django project environment directory

```
cd .../your-venv/
```

3. Set the execution policy variable

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

4. Activate the environment:

```
Scripts/Activate.ps1
```

5. Download the appropriate gdal version for your environment (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)
6. Install gdal from binaries in your venv:

```
pip install C:\...\GDAL-2.4.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

7. Install any other requirements for your project

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is:

1. Install Gdal from whl, for examle: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/][1], if this link unavailable, the whl you need is not so difficult to find.
2. Add to `settings.py` this code (change name of virtualenv if need):

   ````
      OSGEO_VENV = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'venv/Lib/site-packages/osgeo/'
      GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = str(OSGEO_VENV / 'geos_c.dll')
      GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = str(OSGEO_VENV / 'gdal204.dll')
      os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + str(OSGEO_VENV)```
   ````

if previously installed OSGeo, make sure to clean path variables.