# Entry point error when using PostGIS in GeoDjango

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, gdal, geodjango

I am trying to use GeoDjango in my application. I have followed [GeoDjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geodjango-tutorial) and tried to install GeoDjango on windows and install spatial database on postgres with PostGIS. But when I try to run my application following error show up:

[image: The procedure entry point sqlite3_column_origin_name could not be located in the dynamic link library]

It is good point to mention that before this error I was trying to solve another error and solved it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140241/geodjango-on-windows-try-setting-gdal-library-path-in-your-settings/44204170#44204170).
Currently I am using Django 3.0 and GDAL 3.0.0.

This is part of my setting file:

```
....

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'postgis_30_sample',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.gis',
'first.apps.FirstConfig'
]

....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem on Windows 10: Copy `sqlite3.dll` from `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\` and paste it into `C:\Windows\System32\`

Immediately fixed.

This was found using similar solutions from others around SE and other posts. I'm not sure the underlying issues or what happened to cause the problem.